# add a constant value column to a text

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file that has the following format:

```
0.000561859 100.001 0.724805
0.000994887 99.999 0.724788
0.0012519 100.002 0.724732
0.00138511 99.9941 0.724614
.
.
.
```

I want to generate a table that the first column of the table has a constant value got from the first value of third column, say

```
0.724805 0.000561859 100.001 0.724805
0.724805 0.000994887 99.999 0.724788
0.724805 0.0012519 100.002 0.724732
0.724805 0.00138511 99.9941 0.724614
.
.
.
```

How can I do that in Linux with bash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`awk` can be a good option if you want to store the value of the 3rd value of the first row and then print it along all the lines.

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {v=$3}{print v,$0}' file
0.724805 0.000561859 100.001 0.724805
0.724805 0.000994887 99.999 0.724788
0.724805 0.0012519 100.002 0.724732
0.724805 0.00138511 99.9941 0.724614
```

#### Explanation

- `NR` refers to number of line. Hence, with `NR==1 {v=$3}` it stores the value of the 3rd value in the variable `v` when in the line number 1. So this condition is just executed once, one reading the first line.
- Once the value is stored in `v`, and every time a line is read, it prints `v` plus the whole line (`$0`) with `{print v,$0}`. So this condition is executed on every line.

Comment: Thanks but I want the first column be constant value of 0.724805 (the first element of third column).

Comment: Yes @Atoof, I was updating my answer until I really understood your requirement :) See what I posted 1 min ago.

Comment: When I use $ awk 'NR==1 {v=$3}{print v,$0 > file}' file to overwrite the file, the file would be unfinished and number of columns decreased. how can I remove that problem?

Comment: You can do `awk ... {print v, $0}' file > new_file` and then `mv new_file file`.

Comment: Did it work @Atoof? Note that you can accept an answer by clicking on the check mark beside one of the answers that were helpful.

Comment: Dear, How can I add a column after first, which has values calculate from an expression. this expression has a form: (vn+v0)/vl where v0 and vl is the first and last element of 3th column, respectively and vn is nth element of that column.

Comment: @Atoof if it is a new requirement, you'd better ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

This will do the trick:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{a=$3}{print a,$0}' file 
0.724805 0.000561859 100.001 0.724805
0.724805 0.000994887 99.999 0.724788
0.724805 0.0012519 100.002 0.724732
0.724805 0.00138511 99.9941 0.724614
```

Comment: How can I modify this awk if my a is not a part of the input file but it comes from the name of the input file. for example I am trying: `for i in *.txt; do name=$(echo $i | cut -d "." -f 1); TF=$(echo $i | cut -d "_" -f 1); out='outFile.txt'; awk 'NR==1 {a=$TF}{print $0"\t"a}' $i > $name$out` and it is not working. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: I have figured it out by: `sed -i "s/$/\t$TF/" $i`

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v r=1 -v c=3 '{a[NR]=$0}NR==r{p=$(c)}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)print p,a[i]}' file
```

with this line, you just change the `r` (row) and `c` (column) to get the corresponding output. For example, the 3rd column in row 20, you set `r=20 and c=3`. With your example in question, the output is:

```
0.724805 0.000561859 100.001 0.724805
0.724805 0.000994887 99.999 0.724788
0.724805 0.0012519 100.002 0.724732
0.724805 0.00138511 99.9941 0.724614
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ne 'chomp; $p=(split)[2] unless defined $p; print "$p $_\n"' file
```

or (using some more Perl magic, as suggested by *glenn jackman*):

```
perl -lne '$p //= (split)[2]; print "$p $_"' file
```

Output:

```
0.724805 0.000561859 100.001 0.724805
0.724805 0.000994887 99.999 0.724788
0.724805 0.0012519 100.002 0.724732
0.724805 0.00138511 99.9941 0.724614
...
```

Comment: You can use the [`defined-or`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) operator instead of `unless defined`: `perl -lne '$p //= (split)[2]; print "$p $_"'`. The `-l` switch is handy for one-liners (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)